# Select all but first two divs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can use the following to select all divs that are not the first div among their siblings.

```
div:not(:nth-of-type(1))
```

Is there anyway I can select all div's that are not the **first two**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sequential `:not` pseudos, so: `div:not(:nth-of-type(1)):not(:nth-of-type(2))`

http://jsfiddle.net/akm4qnds/

**OR**

Even better, you can use sibilings selectors... Like `div:condition ~ div` that will select every sibiling divs that are after the one with the condition.

So: `div:nth-of-type(2) ~ div` will select every div that comes after the second child.

http://jsfiddle.net/akm4qnds/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `:not` to exclude multiple items

**Example**

```
div:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    background: blue;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/akm4qnds/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

It can even be dome more clear, without specifically writing out the not pseudo selector per element.

U can do this the get the same results:

```
:not(:nth-of-type(-n+2)) {

}

:not(:nth-child(-n+2)) {

}
```

I know its a late answer:P but maybe still usefull to somebody